# styling Google Maps API inside accordion

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-ui-accordion

I finally got maps api implemented into jquery accordion, mainly by changing

```
var map;
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```

to

```
var map = null;  
return new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions);
```

it's functional, however the styling of map and the marker are not visible.

```
var map = null;  

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.744098,-73.95348);

function initializeMap() {

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

     var styles = [ {
                       featureType: "all",
                       stylers: [ { saturation: -100 }, { invert_lightness: true }, { lightness: 2 }, { gamma: 1.29 } ]
                     }];

    return new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions); map.setOptions({styles:styles});

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                });
}



$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();

    $("#accordion").bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.newContent.attr('id') == 'tabThree' && !map)
        {
            map = initializeMap();
        }
    });
});
```

does anyone know of the correct way these styles in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` will leave a function, so everything after

```
return new google.maps.Map($('#mapCanvas')[0], myOptions);
```

...will be  ignored.

Change the order:

```
var styles = [{
               featureType: "all",
               stylers:     [ { saturation: -100 }, 
                              { invert_lightness: true }, 
                              { lightness: 2 }, 
                              { gamma: 1.29 } 
                            ]
                     }];

var map= new google.maps.Map($('#mapCanvas')[0], myOptions); 
map.setOptions({styles:styles});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map
                });

return map;
```

Comment: thanks much for your response, unfortunately this is rendering the map completely blank, maybe because it starts with var map=null. I'm updating original post with entire script.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725229/using-jquery-accordion-hides-most-of-googlemap/9729455#9729455

Comment: thanks again for you help. I have been able to implement the map & accordion but my main problem is styling (hue/sat, gamma, etc) and markers. I haven't come across a single example of a map/accordion which includes styling and markers... is it that it's simply impossible?  sorry for my persistence, I would really like to accomplish this but my js skills aren't primed enough yet... any link to a working example with stylers/markers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Example combining accordion, map, stylers, marker : http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/T8U7b/

Comment: wow, I am truly grateful... thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for!